# Как записать данные в файл? или проблема с кодировкой

Tags: c++, qt

Функция которая записывает данные в файл в формате xml раньше работала в windows-1251, в линуксе такой кодировки не было, исправил

```
m_xmlWriter.setCodec("UTF-8");
```

теперь записываются в файл какие то "кракозябры" , хотя текст  смотрю приходит правильный, тот который нужен.

Comment: Наверное это UTF-8 кракозябры. Посмотри этот файл редактором который умеет переключать кодировки.

Comment: да точно, открыл этот файл на нотпаде, все как надо показывает. Теперь я еще больше не понимаю что надо делать

Comment: Ну так вы сами задали использование UTF-8: `m_xmlWriter.setCodec("UTF-8");`.

Answer (score 0):

Все потому что походу изначально  у меня кодек стоит по умолчанию OC
в мейне дописал:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF8");
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec)
```